# Strategies for deleting a logged-in user in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In my ASP.NET Core MVC application, an administrator may wish to delete a regular user from their organisation. This of course is trivial using the built-in Identity model, using the `UserManager<T>.DeleteAsync()` method.

However, the user may be logged in on multiple devices at the time. I don't need real-time messaging - I'm happy for the deleted user to be returned to the login page upon their next request. SignalR feels like an overkill for this situation.

`Request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` remains true during their session, even though their account has been deleted from the backing store.

My thought process is to override `OnActionExecutingAsync()` on the base controller and check for a valid record in the backing store upon each request and then take appropriate action (e.g. signout + redirect to login), but this feels like a significant overhead to perform on each request, especially since the backing store is CosmosDb and this will cost extra Request Units.

I also need to consider AJAX requests as significant pages within the MVC application have dynamic elements and the user might stay on a single page for a long time.

What's the most effective, lightweight way to check if their user account has been deleted upon next request?

Comment: Since `IsAuthenticated` is tied to a cookie for the user, you cannot find it during deletion of account. Checking for valid account during `OnActionExecutingAsync()` will affect all users so not sure if you want that. How about this: Have a static list that contains deleted ids of the accounts. When you delete, add id to this list. During each request check the list, if id found in list, clear the cookie, remove I'd from list and then redirect to login. Keep in mind that in a web farm the static list will not work.

Comment: CodingYoshi thanks. It’s scaled out across multiple Azure servers so perhaps Azure storage would work. Still affects all users though. I think @citronas answer will work for my situation.

Comment: Well it affects all users very very very very little because all you do is you check an in memory list that may have a few items in it. The approach in the answer will have a much bigger impact because every x minutes (5 in your case) every user will need to be reauthenticated so there will be many more db calls. But if you don't mind the extra db trips and calls, then it should be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, checking upon each request is inefficient. Since you mentioned that an administrator wants to be able to delete manually, a couple of seconds delay between deleting and forcing a logout won't be a problem (it's the same as deleting a couple of seconds later).

Upon defining that you are using .NET Core Identity, you can simply define `SecurityStampValidatorOptions`, such as

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
});
```

This results in the user token being validated every minute. If you set the `ValidationInterval` to `.FromMinutes(0)`, the token is being validated upon each request (I think it's like 3 database call for verifying). My suggestion would be not to take `0` as a value, but rather a value that you think is acceptable for the timespan between a user being deleted manually and him being forced out of the application.

Comment: Works great. Happy with a 5 minute window to keep unnecessary calls to server. Thanks