# How can i revoke claims in ASP.NET Core 6 after deleting a user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, authorization

For example I delete a user, but he can still walk around the site like nothing happened.

For another example, I remove a role from a user to prevent him to access areas on the site that require the role, but until the token expires he can still access them.

So my questions are:

- Is there any way I can revoke the claim or token of the user after modifying his roles?
- What are the alternatives to the default claim based authorization of Entity Framework, where I can remove access from the user instantly?
- What would be the ultimate solution where I don't have to make too many unnecessary calls to the database and I can still do the thing i mentioned in the previous question? For example, could I replace the unnecessary database calls with some kind of memory caching?

Comment: What kind of Authentication do you use? JWT, OAuth2, WS-Federation, something else?
The correct answer depends on the way of implementation of authentication and authorization.

Comment: I'm using the default authentication of ASP.NET and Entity Framework

Comment: Silent log off and log on via owin

Comment: You need to check the cookie which contains the information about identity user, You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468506/validate-authentication-cookie-with-asp-net-core-2-1-3-identity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have the following configuration in place before you delete the user:

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
  options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
});
```

Then you want to signout the user just before you delete the user. Then the user cookie will be invalid and the deleted user cannot login again.

Resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62105305/432074